# Disable sound when a specific App shows a notification

Tags: notifications, oneplus-5t

Is there a way I can allow notifications yet turn off notification sounds for one particular App? I want the notification sound to be off even if my phone is not on vibrate or silent mode.

I am using a One Plus 5T running Android 9.0.8

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean **OxygenOS** 9.0.8, based on Android 9 Pie.

To do this, you can go to **Settings > Apps and Notifications > See all apps**

Scroll down the list to find your app and select it from the list.

Tap **Notifications**.

Choose which notification channel you would like to mute notifications from.

Tap **Behavior** and select your desired behavior.